# Syntax error on line 33 of unexpected "<". Trying to display database data on webpage

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Here is my code to display data from my database on a webpage. Currently I cannot figure out why I'm getting the error I'm getting. There could be more wrong with my code other than what I'm seeing though.

UPDATE: Fixed my most recent error but now I get my echo statement on not being able to get data from my database. Not sure why though.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Display Data from Database</title>
<style type="text/css">
table {
    border: 2px solid red;
    background-color: #FFC;
    }

th  {
    border-botton: 5px solid #000;
    }

td  {
    border-botton: 2px solid #666;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<hl>Display Data from Database</hl>

<?php
include('connect-mysql.php');

$sqlget = "SELECT * FROM 'client table'";
$sqldata = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlget) or die('error getting data');

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>ID</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th></tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlidata, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $row['Client ID'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['Client First Name'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['Client Last Name'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    }

echo "</table>";

?>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have missing quotation mark in line 30

```
echo "<tr><th>ID</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th></tr>
```

correct is

```
echo "<tr><th>ID</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th></tr>";
```

..and correct name of variable $sqlget to $sqliget

```
$sqlget = "SELECT * FROM 'client table'";
```

or vice versa

`$sqldata = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqliget) or die('error getting data');`

---

OK so here is it finally correct

```
$sqlget = "SELECT * FROM `client table`";
```

Comment: Not sure how I missed that. However, now that I fixed that I'm getting this error " syntax error, unexpected 'while' (T_WHILE), expecting ',' or '; "

Comment: you put after " also ; ...</tr>";  ?

Comment: Yeah but now I'm getting this. 

Notice: Undefined variable: sqliget in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC11\data\localweb\display-data.php on line 27

Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC11\data\localweb\display-data.php on line 27
error getting data

I'm assuming a database issue or not typing the correct info in pertaining to my db.

Comment: fixed my error however, I get my echo statement of error getting the data from the database.

Comment: so you must have problem with $dbcon

Comment: I shouldn't though, I have another page where I submit data to my database via webpage and $dbcon has no issue there.

Comment: I made a few more changes and with a few of your suggestions it works now! Thank you much!